# Android Closed Alpha release- can't download version from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, release-management

I have an existing Android app, and I created a new Closed Alpha release in the Google Play console, and invited myself as a tester.

Now I'm signed in to Google Play with the email address I invited as a tester, but **Google Play only shows the existing production version of the app, not the newer version in the alpha release**.  How do I get the alpha release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Google Play**, in the page for the app, you need to scroll down to **"Join the beta"** and tap "Join", **even though this is the alpha release**, not the beta.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different possibilities that I can think of that could be the problem:

1. You have not added yourself correctly - Click on "Closed Testing" then "Manage track". Next go to "Testers" and add yourself to the email lists. Then scroll down to the "How testers join your test" section and open the link to join the test. Make sure the email of your Google account matches the one you added to the testing list. Now press "Become A Tester"
2. Google Play is reviewing the release. If you go to "Publishing overview" you may see that the update is in review. You will be able to download it from Google Play once it has been reviewed. From my experience this usually takes from a 1-5 days but sometimes may take longer.